# Use `git describe --match` In Android build.gradle

Tags: android, git, gradle

Having trouble getting the latest git tag that matches a glob passed in to `git describe` within Gradle. It works fine when in terminal.

I have tried the following:

```
project.ext.releaseVersionName = "git describe --match \'[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*\' --abbrev=0 --tags".execute().text.trim()
```

And

```
def getReleaseVersion = { ->
    try {
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'git', 'describe', '--match "[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*"', '--abbrev=0', 'HEAD'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }
        return stdout.toString().trim()
    }
    catch (ignored) {
        return null
    }
}
```

However both return empty strings. If I don't have the match then everything works correctly. I think it's the glob thats causing the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having the whole of `'--match "[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*"'` in single quotes, you are basically passing an option with that whole string. What you really want is probably to pass the option `--match` with an argument of `[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*`. You should therefore split that argument so that your `commandLine` becomes:

```
commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--match', '[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*', '--abbrev=0', 'HEAD'
```

Alternatively you could switch the `--match` argument to the `--arg=value` syntax, i.e. use `--match=[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*` like you do for `--abbrev=0`.

I've removed the `'bash', '-c'` part as per the comments. If `'bash', '-c'` was to be used, the whole rest should be a single string, as it would work as the value to the `-c` argument of `bash`.

Comment: Tried all of the above, including adding as `--match=` but again, just get a blank string back

Comment: It looks like removing bash and -c worked. `'git', 'describe', '--match', "[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*", '--abbrev=0', 'HEAD'`

Comment: Indeed, with 'bash', '-c' the whole rest should have been one single string as it is the value to the '-c' argument of bash in that case (and would then be further interpreted by bash).